# What is difference between UserGroup and Group?

Tags: liferay

I was sure that group and UserGroup are synonym in liferay. Now I think that i was wrong. What is difference between UserGroup and Group?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find details about UserGroup at link [User Groups](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/user-groups-liferay-portal-6-2-user-guide-16-en)

Group basically refers to Site in Liferay. Site can have set of pages and members. UserGroup/User/Organization can have pages and hence respective Group will be created for it.

Comment: Starting from v6.1 Organizations will not have pages. You have to create an Organization Site to have pages for the Organization.